# Pattern matching by dynamic type as argument to function

Tags: scala

I am playing with scala and I was trying to create a method that would return a list of instances filtered by a given type (passed through parameters of the function):

I tried the following, but it is not even compiling:

```
  trait A

  trait B extends A
  trait C extends A

  case class B1() extends B {}
  case class B2() extends B {}

  case class C1() extends C {}
  case class C2() extends C {}

  def filterByType[F <: A](list: List[A], t: Class[F]): List[F] = list flatMap {
    case f: F => Some(f)
    case _ => None
  }

  val list: List[A] = List(B1(), B2(), C1(), C2()) // type of A

  val filteredList: List[B] = filterByType(list, Class[B]) // This should return a sublist like List(B1(), B2()) and be type of B

  println(filteredList)
```

Is there a way to do something like this in scala? What would be the correct way of doing this?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have also tried passing `classOf[B]` with no luck either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:
*(using [**ClassTag**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/ClassTag.html))*

```
trait A

trait B extends A
final case class B1() extends B
final case class B2() extends B

trait C extends A
final case class C1() extends C
final case class C2() extends C

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def filterByType[F <: A :  ClassTag](list: List[A]): List[F] =
  list.collect {
    case f: F => f
  }
```

Which you can use like this:

```
val list: List[A] = List(B1(), B2(), C1(), C2())

val filteredList: List[B] = filterByType[B](list)
// filteredList: List[B] = List(B1(), B2())
```

---

Note: Due **type erasure** this has some limitations, but it seems it will work for your use case.
For a more general approach I would create my own **typeclass**.

Answer (score 2):

With only `Class[F]` you can do

```
def filterByType[F <: A](list: List[A], t: Class[F]): List[F] = list flatMap {
  case f if t.isInstance(f) => Some(t.cast(f))
  case _ => None
}
```

or shorter but less efficient

```
def filterByType[F <: A](list: List[A], t: Class[F]): List[F] = list flatMap { 
  x => Try { t.cast(x) }.toOption 
}
```

As Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez's answer shows, pattern matching has special support for `: F` is a `ClassTag[F]` is available, but it doesn't extend to anything else.